# How to use "pointcloud_to_laserscan"?

Tags: ros, lidar, pointcloud-to-laserscan, velodyne

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I can view my velodyne point cloud in Rviz but I want to convert the 3-D data into 2-D laserscan.
When I run

```
rosrun pointcloud_to_laserscan pointcloud_to_laserscan_node
```

I can see the there is a new topic `/scan` but I cannot see any laserscan image in Rviz. I found there is no input to the node (not subscribing from anything) as its description says http://wiki.ros.org/pointcloud_to_laserscan by

```
rosrun rqt_graph rqt_graph
```

Can anyone please tell me how to solve it?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/254302/how-to-use-%22pointcloud_to_laserscan%22-?/) by [Bill5785](https://answers.ros.org/users/29209/bill5785/) on ROS Answers with karma: 141 on 2017-02-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

rqt_graph may not show sources or sinks that aren't connected, if you have that option disabled.

From the documentation it looks like the pointcloud_to_laserscan_node takes it input on the `cloud_in` topic, so you should remap that to the pointcloud output topic from your velodyne.

```
rosrun pointcloud_to_laserscan pointcloud_to_laserscan_node cloud_in:=/your_velodyne_points
```

(replace `/your_velodyne_points` with the pointcloud topic from your velodyne)

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2017-02-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Bill5785](https://answers.ros.org/users/29209/bill5785/) on 2017-02-10**:
Wow, thank you very much. It works!